# Google API's Service Account Client Authorization Server-to-Server (Offline Impersonate) Errors

Tags: oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

@note The involved server flow uses google-api-php-client-beta

The goal is to 'insert' an email 'message' into a Google for Work gmail account addressed to a registered email alias.

For this OAuth workflow, I have:

- a Google for Work User with an email alias on a registered add-on domain
- created a 'Project' in console.developers.google.com/apis/
- created a 'Service Account' under the Project
- enabled the Account for 'domain-wide-access'
- added an OAuth 'Client' to the Service Account, along with credentials downloaded as a JSON string
- authorized the Client with 'scopes' in https://admin.google.com/my-domain.tld
- an authorization code allowing the 'Project' to request 'Access Tokens' to do scopes on the User (requires separate single-use client)

The following server code attempts to acquire a Google_Client authorized with the above Credentials and Access Token, while asking for the OAuth Client to impersonate the GFW User mentioned. Thereafter the $client can be used to call services such as Google_Service_Gmail.

Currently, the `$authCreds` is returned with *['error_description'] => 'Could not determine client ID from request'* error message

```
// local const's for testing
const CLNT_GOOGL_SRVC_ACCT_CREDS = '';
const CLNT_GOOGL_API_SRVC_ACCT_CLIENT_ACCESS_CODE = '';
/**
* Returns an authorized API client.
* @return Google_Client the authorized client object
*/
private static function getAuthorizedClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $isSrvcAcct = false;

    if (self::CLNT_GOOGL_SRVC_ACCT_CREDS) {
        $isSrvcAcct = true;
        $creds = json_decode(self::CLNT_GOOGL_SRVC_ACCT_CREDS, true);
    } elseif (defined('CLNT_GOOGL_SRVC_ACCT_CREDS')) {
        $isSrvcAcct = true;
        $creds = json_decode(CLNT_GOOGL_SRVC_ACCT_CREDS, true);
    }

    if ($isSrvcAcct) {
        if (! isset($creds)) {
            acapApp::catchProcessMessage('CLNT_GOOGL_SRVC_ACCT_CREDS  is not valid JSON?', ACAP_DEBUG);

            return;
        }

        self::setServiceClient($client, (array) $creds);
    } else {
        self::setUserClient($client);
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        return $client;
    }
}

private static function setServiceClient(Google_Client $client, array $creds) {
    $client->setAuthConfig($creds);
    $client->setSubject(CLNT_SMTP_OAUTH_USER_EMAIL);

    if (self::CLNT_GOOGL_API_SRVC_ACCT_CLIENT_ACCESS_CODE) {
        $authCode = self::CLNT_GOOGL_API_SRVC_ACCT_CLIENT_ACCESS_CODE;
    } else if (defined('CLNT_GOOGL_API_SRVC_ACCT_CLIENT_ACCESS_CODE')) {
        $authCode = CLNT_GOOGL_API_SRVC_ACCT_CLIENT_ACCESS_CODE;
    }

    if (isset($authCode)) {
        $authCreds = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        if (isset($authCreds['error'])) {
            acapApp::catchProcessMessage('Failure Fetching Auth Token: '.$authCreds['error_description'], ACAP_DEBUG);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting `CLNT_GOOGL_API_SRVC_ACCT_CLIENT_ACCESS_CODE`, but service accounts / clients don't have auth codes. Only users do.

Comment: In general this code is very hard to follow, but if you create an [installed application](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) or [delegate user auth to a service account](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/801#issuecomment-171417538), you'll be good to go.

Comment: the CLNT_* constants are provided by the framework from db store. They're descriptive enough to imagine the values.

Comment: The referenced: 2. Create a "service account" and from your USER account, authorize the client so it shows up here - is complete as outlined above. Tho by *USER acct* I believe you mean API's Project.

Comment: Did you already check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) about OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications? Did you properly follow the guides here?

Comment: Yes! And No.
The Service Acct/delegation/scopes bit had been done - per above.
But my current composer build of php client:
google/apiclient          v2.0.2  Client library for Google APIs
google/apiclient-services v0.5    Client library for Google APIs
google/auth               v0.9    Google Auth Library for PHP

- Has no Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials class
- and Google_Client has no setAssertionCredentials method

I assumed the docs are dated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the .json file u have to use this for auth:
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you're setting the authorisation config *prior* to fetching the access token with the auth code.

For example:

```
<?php
$client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/google_client_id.json'));
$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
```